# algorithmic package, get rid of algorithms numbers

Tags: numbering, algorithms

My question is about algorithmic package.
I have an algorithm which I called A1.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{\bf A1:}
\label{algorithm-A1}
...
```

I have  something like this:

```
Algorithm 1 A1
```

How can I make that I will get

```
Algorithm A1
```

And another question how I can labelling so that when I use `\ref{algorithm-A1}`, then link will appear as A1 in a text.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: Using `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{A\arabic{algorithm}}` should modify the `\label`-`\ref` you're using. However, the bigger question is the use of `{\bf A1}`. What does this represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me, note in particular the line

```
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{A\arabic{algorithm}}
```

which @Werner mentioned in his comment. Note also that this code is an example of a MWE

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{A\arabic{algorithm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
    \label{alg:euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
        \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Test reference: \ref{alg:euclid}

\end{document}
```

Comment: could please comments why does it work. I want to understand what should I change so that I will have various numeration like "Algorihtm A0", "Algorihtm A0M". thank you!