# algorithmic, arbitrary names for algorithms

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, naming

The question is advanced version of my previous [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82679/11860).
I need to name algorithms (package algorithmic) with arbitrary names so it appears like:

```
Algorithm MyAlgo
```

and `\ref{...}` will appear like `MyAlgo`.

Next code is (by [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes)) puts A in front of a number:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{A\arabic{algorithm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
    \label{alg:euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
       \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
       \EndProcedure
   \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Test reference: \ref{alg:euclid}

\end{document}
```

But how to do it for arbitrary algorithm name?

EDIT:
Maybe I was unclear in my question. What I need is assigning to algorithms
arbitrary names without numbering, so that `\ref{...}` will appear as name of the
algorithm.

Comment: Not sure I undestand: `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{MyAlgo\arabic{algorithm}}`?

Comment: I don't understand it too but it works to make names like `Algorithm A1` instead `Algorithm 1 A1`. Now I want to give arbitrary names to algorithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newenvironment{varalgorithm}[1]
  {\algorithm\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{#1}}
  {\endalgorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{varalgorithm}{Euclid}
    \caption{Euclid's algorithm}
    \label{alg:euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
       \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
       \EndProcedure
   \end{algorithmic}
\end{varalgorithm}

\begin{varalgorithm}{Ten}
\caption{Count to ten}\label{alg:ten}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $x \gets 1$ 
\While{$x < 10$} 
\State $x \gets x + 1$ 
\EndWhile 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{varalgorithm}

Test reference: \ref{alg:euclid}

Test reference: \ref{alg:ten}

\end{document}
```

[image]